# how to create an array of Sqlconnection

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sqlconnection

is it possible to create an array of SqlConnection? For expample;

```
SqlConnection[] con = new SqlConnection[4];
con[0].ConnectionString = "my connection string";
```

when write this code it gives no error but when you run it it says:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Yeah, sure, why not? But this also begs the question: Why WOULD you want do that? (just curious)

Comment: It is. The code above won't work though - the connections are not instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After:

```
SqlConnection[] con = new SqlConnection[4];
```

This...

```
con[0].ConnectionString = "my connection string";
```

..is equivalent to:

```
SqlConnection con; // Type defined, but no instance!
con.ConnectionString;
```

What you want is the equivalent of:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
// Accessible, since you now have an instance:
con.ConnectionString = "some string";
```

In your case:

```
var con = new SqlConnection[4];
con[0] = new SqlConnection();
con[0].ConnectionString = "my connection string"
```

Answer (score 6):

You are not assigning the objects in the array list, it should be

```
con[0] = new SqlConnection("my connection string");
```

Moreover when you write,

```
var con = new SqlConnection[4];
```

it does not mean that you have created four new objects of **SqlConnection** rather it states an **Array** object is created which will be holding refrence to four **SqlConnection** objects.
So for storing the objects first you need to create them and then assign them to Array.
**Example**

```
con[0] = new SqlConnection("my connection string 1");
con[1] = new SqlConnection("my connection string 2");
con[2] = new SqlConnection("my connection string 3");
con[3] = new SqlConnection("my connection string 4");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var con = new SqlConnection[4];
con[0] = new SqlConnection("my connection string");
```